# error parsing stylesheet c:\\path\demo\src\demo.xxml in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

I have include css code in my xxml application,but i m getting error error parsing stylesheet c:\path\demo\src\demo.xxml below is my code thanks for help in advance

```
<mx:Style>
    .friendRendererToolTip
    {
        borderStyle : errorTipAbove;
        paddingTop : 3;
        borderColor : 0;
        fontSize : 11;
        paddingLeft : 1;
        backgroundAlpha : 1;
        paddingRight : 12;
        fontWeight : bold;
        height : 33;
        dropShadowEnabled : false;
        color : 16777215;
        alpha : 1;
        paddingBottom : 3;
    }

    Button
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : 5661305;
        color : 0;
        backgroundColor : 14540253;
        cornerRadius : 0;
        fontSize : 13;
        fillAlphas : [1, 0.31, 1, 1];
    }

    .maincontainer
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : 6453933;
        backgroundColor : 15593460;
        cornerRadius : 5;
        verticalGap : 0;
    }

    .mainheader
    {
        paddingTop : 1;
        verticalAlign : middle;
        paddingLeft : 11;
    }

    global
    {
        color : 0;
        fontFamily : Tahoma;
        fontSize : 13;
    }

    .1Slot
    {
        backgroundColor : 16777215;
    }

    .maincontent
    {
        paddingLeft : 9;
        paddingRight : 9;
    }

    Label
    {
        color : 0;
        fontSize : 13;
    }

    .yButton
    {
        cornerRadius : 5;
    }

    ToolTip
    {
        cornerRadius : 0;
    }

    .activityArea
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : 10859729;
        backgroundColor : 16777215;
        disabledColor : 15987699;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

Comment: What error in particular do you have? Please paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS standards for colors like `#FF00FF`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your styles with `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. `errorTipAbove` is not there.  All colors are in bad format, use #RRGGBB hex format. That's all I can see.  Try removing/commenting out lines until you see it work.